# Delete all lines of text that isn't all numbers

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a wordlist that I'd like to extract every line of text from that contains only numbers, to a new file.  What do I do?

Answer (score 8):

To extract lines containing only digits:

```
$ grep -x '[0-9][0-9]*' words >digits
```

The regular expression `[0-9][0-9]*` will match any line contains at least one digit, and the `-x` option to `grep` requires that the whole line matches the given expression.

If your file doesn't have empty lines, you may change it to `grep -x '[0-9]*'`.

If you want lines with *numbers*, delete lines with alphabetic characters instead (easier than trying to construct a regular expression for a generic number):

```
$ grep -v '[a-zA-Z]' words >numbers
```

Both variants using POSIX character classes:

```
$ grep -x '[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*' words >digits
$ grep -v '[[:alpha:]]' words >numbers
```

**Update**: If you want to select the lines containing *floating point numbers* you could use the (extended) regular expression `^[+-]?([0-9]*\.)?[0-9]+$`:

```
$ grep -x -E '[+-]?([0-9]*\.)?[0-9]+' words >floats
```

It all comes down to what kind of "number" we're looking for.

Comment: could use `^[0-9]\+$` instead of `^[0-9][0-9]*$`

Comment: @spasic Yes, and it would be more efficient on large data sets. I kept to only using `*` though as it doesn't need changing in any way when one switches between BREs and EREs.

Answer (score 4):

Delete any line containing letters by `sed` and then put your output to another file:

```
sed '/[a-z]/Id' yourInputFile > yourOutputFile
```

OR if you want to change the original file in-place:

```
sed -i '/[a-z]/Id' yourInputFile
```

Comment: I think there is a typo - should be `/[a-z]/d;/[A-Z]/d` but better to use one regex instead of two.. `/[a-zA-Z]/d`

Comment: or `/[a-z]/Id` to do a case-insensitive match

Comment: @spasic Oh my bad, yes it was typo. Thanks for mentioning. And yes `/[a-z]/Id` is better. I will update my answer. Thanks.